# Analyzing queries by Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I'm learning Entity Framework and I need some explanation.

Let's assume I've created some many-to-many relationship, so that we have table `Students` and `Courses`, and entity of each type can have many entities of the other types.

Next, I have a gridview where I want to display table with two columns describing student's name and all the courses he's assigned to. For this purpose in the `Page_Load` event of my `WebForm` I have the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyModel dbContext = new MyModel();
    GridView1.DataSource = from student in dbContext.Students
                                .Include("Courses").ToList()
                           select new
                                   {
                                       Name = student.StudentName,
                                       Courses = string.Join(",", student.Courses.Select(c => c.CourseName))
                                   };
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Now it works, but notice, that the query isn't really analyzed by Entity Framework, because the line:

```
GridView1.DataSource = from student in dbContext.Students.Include("Courses").ToList()
```

makes that this query is analyzed by LINQ to Objects provider. If I don't use `ToList()` method but instead I would like to write:

```
var query = from student in dbContext.Students.Include("Courses")
            select new { ... };
GridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

then I've got the exception that the `Join()` method is not recognized by `Entity Framework`. I could live with that, but guess the application would work faster if the query was analyzed by EF's engine, am I right?

If so, how I could rewrite the code assigning string to `Courses` property of my anonymous type to get the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only real problem with the way you've done it so far is that, if you want to apply filtering, it would be applied *after* the call to `ToList`, so would be done in memory.
I would split your query into 2 parts. The first part would read the data from the database (and would allow you to include `where` clauses) while the second would map the objects into the format.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var dbContext = new MyModel())
    {
        var students = (from student in dbContext.Students
                        /*optional where clause*/
                        select new
                               {
                                   Name = student.StudentName,
                                   Courses = student.Courses.Select(c => c.CourseName)
                               }).ToList();
        GridView1.DataSource = students.Select(s => new { s.Name, Courses = String.Join(",", s.Courses)}).ToList();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

It's worth mentioning that you could possibly recreate this entirely in EF using `Aggregate`, but I don't really think it's necessary.

Comment: I think `.Include("Courses")` is redundant in this case

Comment: Very true - by selecting the course names in the select clause _before_ the call to `ToList`, which is when the first database call will be made, then the include call is not required.

Comment: @pawel do you get the NRE using your example, or mine?

Comment: @pawel yes, the purpose of include is to specifically eager load an entity, but in my example the selection of courses happens before the entities are loaded. I'm fact, we never load entities, only anonymous types.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding why `Join()` does not work.
The code

```
var query = from student in dbContext.Students.Include("Courses") select new { ... };
```

returns `IQueryable`. At this point your data has not been materialized yet (= there was no call to the database to fetch the entities). This means that everything that is included into your query will be translated to SQL when you later call `ToList()` (= materialize your entities). SQL knows nothing about `string.Join()`, this is why it complains. Your first example works just because LinqToObjects is performed in C#, and not SQL (and thus, it knows how to process `string.Join()`)

More about what you can and cannot include into queries:

[Supported and Unsupported LINQ Methods (LINQ to Entities)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550(v=vs.110).aspx)

[CLR Method to Canonical Function Mapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681(v=vs.110).aspx)

Update:

Though it was not part of the question but it's worth to mention that you may need to implement the pagination for your data. It's unlikely that you want to display hundreds and thousands of items in one datagrid at once. Search for `Take()`.

Comment: To add to this: The proper way to handle this is to do all the parts in one query that can be done in SQL (including where conditions), then AsEnumrable() and then you can chain the next sets of Linq statements to happen in memory.